# how can i solve this toString() error?

Tags: javascript, tostring

The error is produced by `toString()` function.

> "error" "TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

[Image of error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Z48lu.png)

Here is the code :

```
while(  items[i][j].toString().charCodeAt() < items[i][j-1].toString().charCodeAt()  )

  {
    var temp =items[i][j];

    items[i][j]=items[i][j-1];

    items[i][j-1]=temp ;

    j=j-1;

  }
```

Comment: What's the error?

Comment: You need to show us all the relevant code.

Comment: You're not passing anything to `.charCodeAt()`. What do you expect that to do?

Comment: "error"
"TypeError: Cannot read property 'toString' of undefined

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error occurs because, eventually, `[j-1]` is going to try accessing a non-existent index. Assuming a typical array, that'll occur when:

```
var j = 0;
console.log(items[i][j-1]); // undefined

console.log(items[i][-1]); // undefined
```

And, the `undefined` value doesn't allow the use of methods.

To avoid this, the loop should also check whether it's reached that end:

```
while ( j > 0 && items[i][j]... ) {
    // ...
    j=j-1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Are you sure, that j variable never equals 0 ?

If you have two circle like:

```
var arr = [[1,2,3], 
           [4,5,6],
           [7,8,9]];

for (var i = 0; i < arr.length; ++i) {
  for (var j = 0; j < arr[i].length; ++j) {
    arr[i][j - 1].toString() // error
  }
}
```

You have error, because j equals -1 in first time i.e. "undefined", undefined not have toString() method

Set start value for j = 1 in the second circle and you solve this error.